# Cluster points vs isolated points problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let,

$$A = \{0\} \cup \{\tfrac{1}{n}:n \in  \mathbb{N}\}$$

Describe which points in this set are its cluster points, and which are its isolated points.

I know cluster points have a ton of other points around the point and an isolated point has nothing around it. Our definition of cluster points from class is,

Let *S* $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ be a set. A number *x* $\in \mathbb{R}$ is called a cluster point of *S* if for every $\epsilon$ > 0, the set (*x* - $\epsilon$, *x* + $\epsilon$) $\cap$ *S* \ {*x*} is not empty

Comment: What is your definition of a cluster point (some textbooks use limit points, accumulation points, adherence points and other have different notions  for those types of points).

Comment: our definition of a cluster point is "if S is a proper subset of R and S is a set, then x in R is a cluster point if for every epsilon greater than 0, the set (x-epsilon, x +epsilon) intersection S - {x} is not empty. Basically, there are points of S that are arbitrarily close to x.

Comment: Ok, add that to your posting. Once you understand the meaning of all that, you will see that $9$ is the inky cluster point of $A$, and that any other point of $A$ is an isolated point.

Comment: @OliverDiaz what do you mean 9? How can the cluster point be some number like 9 just because I read  the definition?

Comment: I meant $0$… I typed things on my mobile and my thumb coughs 9 instead of $0$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ah it's alright okay so 0 is bad because the limit of 1/n is 0 so you'll have a lot of points around 0 so 0 is the cluster point? But then all those points themselves like 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, and so on are all isolated points?

Comment: $0$ is the only cluster point of $A$. Any other point in $A$ is an isolated point.